# Specifying the Primary Key when using Fluent NHibernate and AsList()

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a scenario in which a User entity has a list of country ids, held as IList.

```
public virtual IList<int> TradeCountries { get; protected set; }
```

Currently this is mapped as

```
HasMany(x => x.TradeCountries).Element("TradeCountryId").AsList(x => x.Column("TradeCountryIndex"));
```

And the resulting table is defined like this

```
create table TradeCountries (
    User_id INT not null,
   TradeCountryId INT null,
   TradeCountryIndex INT not null,
   primary key (User_id, TradeCountryIndex)
)
```

This all works fine - however I'd like to make the PK on TradeCountries be User_id, TradeCountryId. I cannot seem to find a way of doing this when mapping with AsList(). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want your primary key to consist of two fields? (User_id and TradeCounryId)

Comment: Why do you want TradeCountryId in the PK? for uniqueness constraints? NHibernate use the index in the PK because this is what matters to NH. Do you actually need to store each contry's position in the collection?

Comment: @OskarBerggren I wanted to map this as a list simply to avoid the 'delete all / re-insert all' behaviour I've experienced when mapping components as set or bag

Comment: Hmm... I wouldn't expect you to get the delete-all-reinsert with sets - since the elements are unique, the owner reference and the element value/id forms a unique key which enables targeting individual rows. To enable this you must specify not-null="true" for the element, but unfortunately this feature seems to be missing from the documentation, and not exposed in Fluent NHibernate (though it would probably be fairly easy to add). Anyway, there is also the idbag to prevent such issues.

Answer (score 3):

The conversion of collections used in Fluent NHibernate goes [(as described here)](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping) this way:

```
// <set>
public virtual ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }    
HasMany(x => x.Children); // <set />

// <bag>
public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }    
HasMany(x => x.Children); // <bag />

// <list>
public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }    
HasMany(x => x.Children).AsList(...; // <list />
```

The essence / difference of these mappings is in detail described in documentation [Understanding Collection performance](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-taxonomy) and [Ayende's post: `<list>`)](http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list). **Extract**:

> ...while `<set/>` is an unordered collection, of unique elements, a `<list/>`
>   is a collection of elements where the order matter, and duplicate
>   elements are allowed...

Other words, when using `<list>` you have to keep PK on the **key** and **index** column, because there could be duplicates.

In your case, just `<bag>` mapping (without explicit `.AsList()` call) could be efficient enough, you can remove the index column, and move PK to **key** and **element** (User_id, TradeCountryId).

*NOTE: C# IList still allows to have more "same" elements, you should check it on business layer*